# X.509 strong authentication protocols

Tags: rsa, protocol-design, tls, certificates

Is there also a protocol definition in X.509? In "Handbook of Applied Cryptography" by A. Menezes there is a reference to X.509 strong authentication protocol, nevertheless, I could not find the definition of the actual protocol, i.e. which massages are passing between the partners, in the source quoted, i.e. ITU-T X.509. Can any one help with this?
Thanks

Comment: Doesn’t ring a bell. Could you share that quote (or page number) from HoAC?

Comment: Page 511 protocol 12.40

Answer (score 1):

The strong authentication protocol referred to in the book is defined in the Annex N of "X.509 (10/16)" published by the ITU https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-X.509

Here is an excerpt of the standard for the two-way and strong three-way protocols:

> ### Annex N
>
> **Considerations on strong authentication**
>
> Strong authentication makes use of PKI as specified by this Specification, which
>   provides the basic approach to authentication. However, many authentication procedures
>   employing this approach are possible. In general, it is the business of a specific
>   application to determine the appropriate procedures, so as to meet the security
>   policy of the application.
>
> *NOTE – This Specification does not specify the procedures in the detail required
>   for implementation. However, additional standards could be envisaged that would do 
>   so, either in an application-specific or in a general-> purpose way.*
>
> - Two-way authentication, described in clause N.3, involves, in addition, a reply from 
>     B to A. It establishes, in addition, the following:
>
>   - that the authentication token generated in the reply actually was generated by 
>       B and was intended to be sent to A;
>   - the origin, integrity and timeliness of the authentication token sent in 
>       the reply;
>   - (optionally) the mutual confidentiality of part of the tokens.
> - Three-way authentication, described in clause N.4, involves, in addition, a
>     further transfer from A to B. It establishes the same properties as the two-way
>     authentication, but does so without the need for association timestamp checking.